# How to generate the function stack trace of the last request made?

Tags: debugging

Is there a module that can essentially show you the function stack trace of the last request made?

Say I have a form that I submit.  After the page loads with the result from the request, I would like to see a list of all the functions that were called, start to finish, that resulted in the currently loaded page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function trace will only show you the function calls that lead directly to that piece of code.

PHP provides the functions `debug_print_backtrace()` for that, which is however not very readable but it will result a huge amount of text. devel.module provides a `ddebug_backtrace()`function, which us much easier to read.

To see all function calls of a single page, you need to install a profiler like XhProf.

Answer (score 2):

#### XDebug

You can use PHP XDebug extension with the following options:

- start/stop by `xdebug_start_trace()`/`xdebug_stop_trace()` at the specific places (e.g. before form submit),
- set `xdebug.auto_trace=1` in `php.ini` for full trace,
- use `xdebug_print_function_stack()` to display your current function stack,
- use `xdebug.remote_enable=1` in `php.ini` to use debugger directly from IDE for step-by-step debugging.

Check: [XDebug Docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/).

See my suggested [`xdebug.ini`](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/conf/php/xdebug.ini) config file for PHP.

#### [DTrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace)

If your system supports DTrace (e.g. OS X) and your PHP has been configured with [DTrace static probes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.dtrace.php) (`php -i | grep dtrace`), the following command will trace all your function calls:

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'php*:::function-entry { printf("%Y: PHP function-entry:\t%s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2); }'
```

This should work in Apache, if not, you may re-run your CMS by using builtin PHP server, e.g.:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

then access your site at http://localhost:8080/, so when you submit the form - you should see trace output containing all functions that were called as result of loaded page.

For more scripts, check my [`dtruss-lamp`](https://github.com/kenorb/dtruss-lamp) repository.