# How can I trace the source of a redirect error listed in Administration -> Reports?

Tags: debugging, log-messages

Under `Reports -> Recent log messages`, I have a large number of errors such as the following:

- Type: access denied
- Date: November 7, 2013
- User: Anonymous
- Location: https://mysite.com/ja/user/en/user/register
- Referrer: http://mysite.com/ja/user/en/user/register
- Message: user/en/user/register
- Severity: warning

I have a multilingual site (English `en` and Japanese `ja`), so I assume that somewhere there is a bad link or a module is outputting a bad link to the registration page.  How can I find out where?  The only clue I have is this entry in the recent error log.

When I visit the link (`http://mysite.com/ja/user/en/user/register`), I get a "The page isn't redirecting properly.  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Start checking any nodes/blocks that might have a hardcoded link to the registration page. Have a look also at [Link Checker](https://drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module - if might detect the source.

Comment: yeah looks like a typical hard-coded relative href not set right

Comment: Is there a way to query the database to identify links to `user/register`?  There's a lot of content, including links in Panels and Views, and the link(s) could be any number of places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the name of the failing redirect URI (such as `user/register`), the best is to scan through your database and look for redirect entries, e.g. using `drush`:

```
drush sql-dump --ordered-dump | grep "user/register"
```

---

Alternatively add `dd()` (from Devel) into [`drupal_goto()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) and log the backtrace of each call into the file, e.g.

```
dd(debug_backtrace(FALSE, 5));
```

and check `drupal_debug.txt` in your `tmp` folder.

---

Another trick include using [DTrace](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.dtrace.php) and hook into static probes (if your PHP supports that: `php -i | grep dtrace`), for example (after running the script):

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'php*:::function-entry { printf("%Y: PHP function-entry:\t%s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2); }'
```

then you may grep it and look for specific functions such as `drupal_goto`, so you may append to above:

```
| grep -B5 drupal_goto > trace.txt
```

so this will log into file all calls to `drupal_goto` with 5 function calls before.

See also: [How to generate the function stack trace of the last request made?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/29781/1908)